# C# - Transpose an object into a list of values

Tags: c#, angular, transpose

I have a simple object as below:

```
public partial class RepackViewIndex
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateRequested { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string RepackFrom { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string RepackTo { get; set; }

    public int? Qty { get; set; }

    public int? ReworkTime_c { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string TTLTime { get; set; }

    public int? QtyCompleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PlannedCompletion { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Priority { get; set; }
}
```

However, i want to display this object as a table in the front end. (The front end is in Angular2). I thought the best approach would be to convert the object into A Dictionary or similar however i am not sure on the best approach or how to implement so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Or if any angular2 gurus out there have a way of using the data as it is to display in a table i am all ears. I am using PrimeNG for my components.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Serialize to JSON the use `for..in` to iterate the keys in JavaScript, you can then build out your table in Angular as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want your values as dictionary by property name, you could add an instance method and use reflection:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var prop in GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        dict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this));
    }

    return dict;
}
```